# Markov chain converges to Normal Distribution. How to increase standard deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-chains, recursion, markov-process

I am creating an MC (using the following recursive function). It is about a game that each side has different probs of scoring 1 point, 2 points, 3 points or no score (scoreDifference is the score side A - score side B, time is 100 time units, and timeRemaining is what's left.

```
f[t, d] =


If[t > 100, 0,
       If[d == scoreDifference && t == timeRemaining, 1,
        p1h*f[t + 1, d - 1] + p2h*f[t + 1, d - 2] + p3h*f[t + 1, d - 3] +
         p1a*f[t + 1, d + 1] + p2a*f[t + 1, d + 2] + p3a*f[t + 1, d + 3] +
         pns*f[t + 1, d]
        ]
       ];
```

At timeremaining = 0 I get all the possible differences. This converges to a normal distribution (x-axis is the difference, the y-axis is probability).
Example:

```
p1h = 0.0375 # side A
p2h = 0.05625
p3h = 0.0125
p1a = 0.0327083 # side B
p2a=  0.0490625
p3a = 0.0109028
pns = 0.801076 # noone scores
```

[image]

How can I manipulate this in order to achieve greater (or smaller) standard deviation?
In this example:

```
E[x] = 11.5
V[x] = 335.6774
SD[x] = 18.3215
```

Comment: Will it help if i convert it to inhomogeneous process? Somehow chamge the probabilities if a player is leading over the other?

Answer (score 1):

That is clearly obtained by increasing the probabilities for larger differences ($p_3$'s) wrt those for smaller.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried it. The change is not big enough to get what I want

Comment: @Tom: well, if points go from $0$ to $3$, and increasing the prob. for $3$ points does not provide what you want, that only means that the difference in points at each turn is too little. Don't know how you want to alter the rules to cope with that.